# How to get file name and url file when clicked in browser for download

Tags: android

I'm looking to get the file name and url file when clicking to download from a browser on Android. I tried to use method when click download in site show file name and url file but it's not showing them correctly.

[image: Example of display]

How can I get it to be correct?

Comment: Oh, that's a perfect path url encoded... %20 just means "space". So you have to urldecode the string first. The link itself MUST contain urlencoded, otherwise some browsers (i look at you, IE!) might choke.

Comment: Thanks solve my problem

Comment: @MirHussain Glad you solved it! You could post the way you solved it as an answer to your own question so that anyone who comes across this post later with the same issue can see how you fixed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use this code for get url in application and solve my problem

```
Uri data = getIntent().getData();
    if (data != null) {
        String url = data.toString();
        edtlink.setText(url);
}
```